# Remove module_statuses.json file from Laravel Modules and always enable all modules

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-modules

I'm using a Laravel Modules package (https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v6/introduction) to manage Laravel applications in different Modules. It resolves a lot of manual handling of modules.

There is an option to enable and disable modules. The information is stored in module_statuses.json files. I want to consider all modules as enabled and don't want to enable each, separately.

It is creating problems in two cases.

- I have an option in UI to create modules dynamically
- The other one is my application is also handling multi-tenancy.

Is there any way to skip this file?